# how to count listbox items while running a for each loop in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, for-loop, vb.net-2010

I have a list of links and need to check some data in it.

i placed all the list in a listbox and each item is verified for some result

now i want to see how many items are processed and how many are still need to process

Example: in a label it must display total count of items and items completed and it must change once a item is finished.

over view of my code is:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
```

For Each item In ListBox2.Items
!!!!==== MY CODE====!!!!
Next Item
End Sub

Once an item is finished label must change the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a counter variable inside the For Each and use it.

```
Dim i as integer = 0
For Each item In myListBox.Items
    // your code goes here
    // do you need to check if your code went ok?
    i = i+1
    label.Text = string.Format("Processing item {0} of {1}", i, myListBox.Items.Count)
Next item
```

Forgive me if i'm syntactically wrong there, long time I haven't used VB.